# Eclipse Helios - files and directories missing from Working Set

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

When I create a working set - with no filters - I see all my PHP files in the directory heirachy EXCEPT for in the last nested directory. In this directory the PHP files are not shown in PHP Explorer even though they certainly exist in the directory. This does not happen when viewing the project without a working set defined.

Any ideas?

**Edit**
I have now found that it is happening with other projects and whole directories with javascript files are going missing. I just recreated the problem like this:

1. created a PHP project and imported source for a clean wordpress installation
2. created a working set based on the whole project
3. took a screen shot of it; notice the directory `my_wordpress.co.uk/wp-includes/js/crop/`; here is the screen shot:
   [image: Full working set]
   <sub>(source: [internetsolutionsni.co.uk](http://www.internetsolutionsni.co.uk/eclipse_error/working_set_full.jpg))</sub>
4. edit the current active working set and unticked (removed) the directory `wp-content`
   now the working set is minus the `wp-content` folder, but also several other folders have 'disappeared' including `my_wordpress.co.uk/wp-includes/js/crop/`; see the resulting screen shot:
   [image: Resulting working set]
   <sub>(source: [internetsolutionsni.co.uk](http://www.internetsolutionsni.co.uk/eclipse_error/working_set_short.jpg))</sub>

Comment: did you manually create that folder, or pasted it from somewhere else?

Comment: Did you try to refresh your project?

Comment: OK - I reinstalled Halios and THOUGHT that I'd solved it.. but it's back. It doesn't happen all the time.. I'll try and find unique conditions for it. Nothing changes if I refresh the project - and the folder was not pasted in, it was always part of the whole imported project.

Comment: I've just loaded up the PDT and Wordpress, and followed your instructions.  I got the same exact results - the other directories in js disppeared.  Time permitting, I'll take a closer look.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reproduce the problem. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Did you look in the Error Log View for any interesting or potentially relevant errors?

Comment: @Bert F - no errors were added to the log when switching in and out of working sets. (Sometimes I have to close and re-open PHP Explorer view in order to refresh the Windows Working Set, otherwise it does not display when switching out of a working set.) But there were warnings (not error) in the log on Halios startup... !MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.sql.h2.H2FileDao" and !MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.sql.h2.H2ContainerDao" ... but no idea if this is significant.

Answer (score 0):

I have a (hacky) fix to this problem:

Create your working sets, it doesn't matter that they're missing files or directories, just get them all created using the wizard.

Close eclipse completely.

Open **/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml**

In each workingSet element, add the following as the first child element:

```
<item elementID="=WORKINGSET_NAME" factoryID="org.eclipse.dltk.ui.PersistableModelElementFactory"/>
```

When you restart eclipse you should find it works as expected, need to do some more testing on adding new directories etc. but so far all looks good!

Comment: Also, I'm only finding this issue on one of my Windows machines, despite it working perfectly on another Windows box and Ubuntu.